# R -- mean function of column section

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to include a mean calculation as part of a larger code. The idea is to calculate the mean from a series of values within a column, but not all the column.

For example, from `column_x` (10 entries) in `yFile`, calculate the mean of the last 4 values:

```
column_x
1
5
8
3
0
3
3
7
9
9

Result = 7
```

This is what I've got:

```
avg_subx <- mean(yFile$column_x, 7:10, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)
```

But for some reason, the result I am getting back is not the correct value.
Could you help me finding out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Index the column you pass explicitly like: `mean(yFile$column_x[(nrow(yFile) - 3):nrow(yFile)])`

Comment: The problem is that it is not recognizing the line limitation and is averaging the entire column instead. Any advise on how to limit the average to the last four entries? Thanks!

Comment: If you use the code I pasted it will work.

Comment: It is not clear to me what criteria you intend to use for filtering the values. For instance, if it's positional such as "last 4", then VictorCortés' use of `tail` is correct; if it's absolute positional, then I would think `mean(yFile$column_x[7:10],...)` would suffice; if it's based on value, then you can use variable indexing using something similar to Zach's comment or perhaps with `Filter(...,yFile$column_x,...)`. Please provide one or more representative sample vector(s) (does not need to be a full `data.frame` since you are just doing things per-column).

Comment: It does work! thanks! I am assuming the same specifications are true for the sum function, right?

Comment: it is a string of data, say co2 emissions, over time at different sites (A, B, and C). So you would have a column per site, and one value of daily emission per day (1 to 365 days). Now, I want extract the average daily emissions for the period day 67 - day 83. The function Zach provided works fine in this case.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried with `tail` function? With `tail` you can select the last `n` values of a `data frame` or a `vector`.

**example**:

```
avg_subx <- mean(tail(yFile$column_x,4))
```

In this case you're selecting the las 4 values.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: I actually wanted to be able to specify position. In my real data set it does not correspond necessarily to the last four, but this will be very helpful in other situations, thanks!

Comment: In that case you'll have to index your `vector` like this:
`avg_subx <- mean(yFile$column_x[c(1,5,7,8)])`